# What exactly is "exit" in PowerShell?

Tags: powershell

You can exit PowerShell by typing `exit`. So far so good. But what exactly is this?

```
PS Home:\> gcm exit
Get-Command : The term 'exit' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Ch
eck the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:4
+ gcm <<<<  exit
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (exit:String) [Get-Command], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetCommandCommand
```

So it's neither a cmdlet, function, script or program. It leaves the question *what* exactly it is.

This unfortunately also means that one can't create aliases to `exit`:

```
PS Home:\> New-Alias ^D exit
PS Home:\> ^D
Cannot resolve alias '♦' because it refers to term 'exit', which is not recognized as a cmdlet, function, operable prog
ram, or script file. Verify the term and try again.
At line:1 char:2
+ ♦ <<<<
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (♦:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : AliasNotResolvedException
```

Are there any more such commands which are no commands?

**ETA:** Just for reference: I know I can simply wrap it into a function. My profile has the lines

```
# exit with Ctrl+D
iex "function $([char]4) { exit }"
```

in them. My question was just to know what exactly this command is.

Answer (score 127, accepted):

It's a reserved keyword (like return, filter, function, break).

[Reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_language_keywords?view=powershell-6#exit)

Also, as per Section 7.6.4 of Bruce Payette's [Powershell in Action](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1932394907):

> But what happens when you want a script to exit from within a function defined in that script? **...** To make this easier, Powershell has the **exit keyword**.

Of course, as other have pointed out, it's not hard to do what you want by wrapping exit in a function:

```
PS C:\> function ex{exit}
PS C:\> new-alias ^D ex
```

Comment: According to `Get-Help Exit-PSSession` _You can also use the Exit keyword to end an interactive session. The effect is the same as using Exit-PSSession._ So it also says `Exit` is a keyword. However, it appears that the quote cannot be taken to imply that `Exit` and `Exit-PSSession` are equivalent in all cases. The exit keyword can be used with an argument which can convert to `[int]`, and in that case that number will be the exit code. For example `Exit 42`.

Comment: I have to say, this answer is completely and demonstrably false. I have put a function in my $profile and in that function I put an "exit" on a certain condition and it does NOT exit the function, it exits the entire console. I've wasted quite a few hours searching what can leave a function wihout killing the console session and I'm stumped. The above is definitely wrong.

Comment: So, maybe this behaviour is because $profile is dotsourced into the current session? In that case, then the `exit` inside a function there completely fails to do what is described by Bruce Payette in the above. If that is the case, then that part of the answer is just wrong, because a dotsourced script is *still* a script that is called by the console session, so it's still a script(!), but how then can we exit a function without quitting the console session if the script has been dotsourced?

Comment: @YorSubs if you read the linked reference, it notes that `exit` "Causes PowerShell to exit a script or a PowerShell instance." Exiting the instance is the expected behavior. If you want to exit a function, you can simply use `return`. From the same reference: "Causes PowerShell to leave the current scope, such as a script or **function**, and writes the optional expression to the output."
That `return` for return values (including void) did not become idiomatic in PowerShell functions is bizarre coming from other programming languages, but that's besides the point.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a ^d alias to exit, try doing the exit inside of a script block invocation.

```
Invoke-Expression "Function $([Char]4) { Invoke-Command -ScriptBlock { Exit } }"
```

Comment: Works in Windows Terminal with PowerShell 7+ and Windows PowerShell 5.1. Nifty trick, and it does seem to partially answer part of the question.