# How to Use -confirm in PowerShell

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to take user input and before proceeding I would like get a message on screen and than a confirmation, whether user wants to proceed or not. I'm using the following code but its not working:

```
write-host "Are you Sure You Want To Proceed:"  -Confirm
```

Answer (score 179):

`-Confirm` is a switch in most PowerShell cmdlets that forces the cmdlet to ask for user confirmation. What you're actually looking for is the [`Read-Host`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee176935.aspx) cmdlet:

```bsh
$confirmation = Read-Host "Are you Sure You Want To Proceed:"
if ($confirmation -eq 'y') {
    # proceed
}
```

or the [`PromptForChoice()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.management.automation.host.pshostuserinterface.promptforchoice%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) method of the host user interface:

```bsh
$title    = 'something'
$question = 'Are you sure you want to proceed?'

$choices = New-Object Collections.ObjectModel.Collection[Management.Automation.Host.ChoiceDescription]
$choices.Add((New-Object Management.Automation.Host.ChoiceDescription -ArgumentList '&Yes'))
$choices.Add((New-Object Management.Automation.Host.ChoiceDescription -ArgumentList '&No'))

$decision = $Host.UI.PromptForChoice($title, $question, $choices, 1)
if ($decision -eq 0) {
    Write-Host 'confirmed'
} else {
    Write-Host 'cancelled'
}
```

---

**Edit:**

As M-pixel pointed out in the comments the code could be simplified further, because the choices can be passed as a simple string array.

```bsh
$title    = 'something'
$question = 'Are you sure you want to proceed?'
$choices  = '&Yes', '&No'

$decision = $Host.UI.PromptForChoice($title, $question, $choices, 1)
if ($decision -eq 0) {
    Write-Host 'confirmed'
} else {
    Write-Host 'cancelled'
}
```

Comment: It works without the explicit types and object declarations: `$decision = $Host.UI.PromptForChoice('something', 'Are you sure you want to proceed?', @('&Yes'; '&No'), 1)`

Comment: FYI, in a rich environment (like PowerShell ISE), `$message` is the title of the pop-up window.  So, you really need to keep that short, and put your whole message (including the question) into the `$question` variable. (`$message` should really just be renamed to `$title`).

Comment: Hmm I'm getting this on PS 4.0 running on Exchange Management Shell, might have to use the full explicit object declarations: Cannot convert argument "choices", with value: "System.Object[]", for "PromptForChoice" to type
"System.Collections.ObjectModel.Collection`1[System.Management.Automation.Host.ChoiceDescription]"

Answer (score 26):

This is a simple loop that keeps prompting unless the user selects 'y' or 'n'

```
$confirmation = Read-Host "Ready? [y/n]"
while($confirmation -ne "y")
{
    if ($confirmation -eq 'n') {exit}
    $confirmation = Read-Host "Ready? [y/n]"
}
```

Comment: The `break` will exit the while loop properly instead of `exit`! It does depend on the context: [break vs exit vs return](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2022326/terminating-a-script-in-powershell#answer-23703056) @dallyack

Comment: Don't use `read-host` for confirmations, and don't use `exit` to `break`.

Comment: This was perfecto! I absolutley wanted to `exit` NOT `break`.

Comment: Use a doo...while loop and you don't need to repeat the Read-Host line:

`do { $yn = Read-Host "Ready? [y/n]";  if ($yn-eq 'n') {exit}; } while($yn -ne "y")`

Answer (score 24):

`Read-Host` is one example of a cmdlet that `-Confirm` does not have an effect on.`-Confirm` is one of PowerShell's Common Parameters specifically a Risk-Mitigation Parameter which is used when a cmdlet is about to make a change to the system that is outside of the Windows PowerShell environment. Many but not all cmdlets support the `-Confirm` risk mitigation parameter.

As an alternative the following would be an example of using the `Read-Host` cmdlet and a regular expression test to get confirmation from a user:

```
$reply = Read-Host -Prompt "Continue?[y/n]"
if ( $reply -eq 'y' ) { 
    # Highway to the danger zone 
}
```

The `Remove-Variable` cmdlet is one example that illustrates the usage of the `-confirm` switch.

```
Remove-Variable 'reply' -Confirm
```

Additional References: [CommonParameters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_commonparameters?view=powershell-5.1), [Write-Host](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/write-host?view=powershell-5.1), [Read-Host](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/read-host?view=powershell-5.1), [Comparison Operators](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_comparison_operators?view=powershell-5.1), [Regular Expressions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_regular_expressions?view=powershell-5.1), [Remove-Variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/remove-variable?view=powershell-5.1)

Comment: No need to bring out regex. `-eq` is case insensitive.  `$reply -eq 'y'` would suffice.

Answer (score 16):

Here is the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/developer/cmdlet/how-to-request-confirmations) from Microsoft on how to request confirmations in a cmdlet. The examples are in C#, but you can do everything shown in PowerShell as well.

First add the `CmdletBinding` attribute to your function and set `SupportsShouldProcess` to `true`. Then you can reference the `ShouldProcess` and `ShouldContinue` methods of the `$PSCmdlet` variable.

Here is an example:

```
function Start-Work {
    <#
    .SYNOPSIS Does some work
    .PARAMETER Force
        Perform the operation without prompting for confirmation
    #>
    [CmdletBinding(SupportsShouldProcess=$true)]
    param(
        # This switch allows the user to override the prompt for confirmation
        [switch]$Force
    )
    begin { }
    process {
        if ($PSCmdlet.ShouldProcess('Target')) {
            if (-not ($Force -or $PSCmdlet.ShouldContinue('Do you want to continue?', 'Caption'))) {
                return # user replied no
            }

            # Do work
        }

    }
    end { }
}
```

Comment: I think there's a missing closing bracket (`}`) exactly where the comment `# Do work` is.

Comment: Pretty sure it's  just weird formatting in the markdown, did you try pasting the code into an IDE to see if there were any compiler errors?

Comment: No, I just saw that you don't have a closing bracket for your `ShouldProcess` condition, but maybe it is a weird formatting that's why I said I think

Comment: I fixed the formatting issue so the braces line up.

Comment: Almost there...

Answer (score 11):

`write-host` does not have a `-confirm` parameter.

You can do it something like this instead:

```
    $caption = "Please Confirm"    
    $message = "Are you Sure You Want To Proceed:"
    [int]$defaultChoice = 0
    $yes = New-Object System.Management.Automation.Host.ChoiceDescription "&Yes", "Do the job."
    $no = New-Object System.Management.Automation.Host.ChoiceDescription "&No", "Do not do the job."
    $options = [System.Management.Automation.Host.ChoiceDescription[]]($yes, $no)
    $choiceRTN = $host.ui.PromptForChoice($caption,$message, $options,$defaultChoice)

if ( $choiceRTN -ne 1 )
{
   "Your Choice was Yes"
}
else
{
   "Your Choice was NO"
}
```

Comment: This is way better, I think, since there will be 3 otpions. The last one will be help and there you can add a bit more clear explanation what actually "yes" and "no" are doing.

Answer (score 10):

For when you want a 1-liner

```
while( -not ( ($choice= (Read-Host "May I continue?")) -match "^(y|n)$")){ "Y or N ?"}
```

Comment: @BrainSlugs83 You took the trouble to comment on / downvote most of the answers using read-host? Will you also get the PowerShell docs updated too, to not say, `The Read-Host cmdlet reads a line of input from the console. You can use it to prompt a user for input?`  -- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/read-host?view=powershell-6

Comment: Warning: you one-liner will exit if the entered string contain a "y" or "n" whatever its position !
Fix:

`while( -not ( ($choice= (Read-Host "May I continue?")) -match "^(y|n)$")){ "Y or N ?"}`

Answer (score 9):

```
Write-Warning "This is only a test warning." -WarningAction Inquire
```

from:
https://serverfault.com/a/1015583/584478

Answer (score 2):

Here's a solution I've used, similiar to Ansgar Wiechers' solution;

```
$title = "Lorem"
$message = "Ipsum"

$yes = New-Object System.Management.Automation.Host.ChoiceDescription "&Yes", "This means Yes"
$no = New-Object System.Management.Automation.Host.ChoiceDescription "&No", "This means No"

$options = [System.Management.Automation.Host.ChoiceDescription[]]($yes, $no)

$result = $host.ui.PromptForChoice($title, $message, $Options, 0)

Switch ($result)
     {
          0 { "You just said Yes" }
          1 { "You just said No" }
     }
```

Comment: If they close the dialog, `$result` will not be 0 or 1.

Answer (score 2):

A slightly prettier function based on [Ansgar Wiechers's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24649481/1394393). Whether it's actually more useful is a matter of debate.

```
function Read-Choice(
   [Parameter(Mandatory)][string]$Message,
   [Parameter(Mandatory)][string[]]$Choices,
   [Parameter(Mandatory)][string]$DefaultChoice,
   [Parameter()][string]$Question='Are you sure you want to proceed?'
) {
    $defaultIndex = $Choices.IndexOf($DefaultChoice)
    if ($defaultIndex -lt 0) {
        throw "$DefaultChoice not found in choices"
    }

    $choiceObj = New-Object Collections.ObjectModel.Collection[Management.Automation.Host.ChoiceDescription]

    foreach($c in $Choices) {
        $choiceObj.Add((New-Object Management.Automation.Host.ChoiceDescription -ArgumentList $c))
    }

    $decision = $Host.UI.PromptForChoice($Message, $Question, $choiceObj, $defaultIndex)
    return $Choices[$decision]
}
```

Example usage:

```
PS> $r = Read-Choice 'DANGER!!!!!!' '&apple','&blah','&car' '&blah'

DANGER!!!!!!
Are you sure you want to proceed?
[A] apple  [B] blah  [C] car  [?] Help (default is "B"): c
PS> switch($r) { '&car' { Write-host 'caaaaars!!!!' } '&blah' { Write-Host "It's a blah day" } '&apple' { Write-Host "I'd like to eat some apples!" } }
caaaaars!!!!
```

Answer (score 1):

This version asks if the user wants to perform an action before continuing with the rest of the script.

```
DO
{
$confirmation = Read-Host "Do want Action before continue? [Y/N]"
if ($confirmation -eq 'y') {
   write-Host "Doing the Action"
   }
} While (($confirmation -ne 'y') -and ($confirmation -ne 'n'))
```

Answer (score 0):

I prefer a popup.

```
$shell = new-object -comobject "WScript.Shell"
$choice = $shell.popup("Insert question here",0,"Popup window title",4+32)
```

If $choice equals 6, the answer was Yes
If $choice equals 7, the answer was No

Comment: This has the major disadvantage that it won't adapt to the host you're using. So if you're remoting into a server, for example, this will fail at best or freeze the script at worst.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you are looking for.

To have a function or script behave as a cmdlet in this regard, you should use `ConfirmImpact='High'` in the `CmdletBinding` as well.

Then PowerShell will automatically prompt the user.

To improve on the answer somewhat above from Zack, use...

```
function Start-Work {
  [CmdletBinding(SupportsShouldProcess, ConfirmImpact='High')]
  param(
  )

  if (-not $PSCmdlet.ShouldProcess('')) {
     return
  }

  Write-Host 'Process did run'

}
```

`Start-Work -Confirm:$false` will still run the function without confirmation.

The prompting will depend on the preference variable `$ConfirmPreference`, that defaults to 'High'.
(See [about_Preference_Variables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_preference_variables?view=powershell-7.3#confirmpreference))