# What is the effect of the -ErrorAction Stop for an Invoke-Expression statement?

Tags: powershell

I am using Invoke-Expression on each line of a file.  If one of the lines causes an error, I would like to stop executing.  I have tried using -ErrorAction Stop but it has no effect.

What is supposed to be the effect of the following?

```
gc -Path "fileWithErrorOnSomeLine.txt" | % {Invoke-Expression "$_" -ErrorAction Stop }
```

How can one exit the loop immediately if the expression invocation creates an error?

Note:  The following change does not stop iterating through the file contents

```
gc -Path "fileWithErrorOnSomeLine.txt" | % {Invoke-Expression "$_" -ErrorAction Stop } -ErrorAction Stop
```

Comment: [Don't use `Invoke-Expression`](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/powershell/2011/06/03/invoke-expression-considered-harmful/).

Answer (score 0):

Use try-catch

```
"tester" > testing.txt
"test2" >> .\testing.txt
"get-childitem" >> .\testing.txt

gc .\testing.txt |  % { 
    try { invoke-expression "$_" -ErrorAction Stop
    }
    catch { 
        write-warning "error : $_ "
        break
    }
}
```

More info on how to terminate a loop:
[Terminating a script in PowerShell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2022326/terminating-a-script-in-powershell)